# Property and __getattr__ compatibility issue with AttributeError

Tags: python, properties

I just encountered an unexpected behavior. This is a simple class with a `__getattr__` method and a property attribute with a typo inside:

```
class A(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if not attr.startswith("ignore_"):
            raise AttributeError(attr)

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return self.some_typo

a = A() # Instantiating
a.ignore_this # This is ignored
a.prop # This raises an Attribute Error
```

This is the expected outcome (the one I get if `__getattr__` is commented):

```
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'some_typo'
```

And this is what I get:

```
AttributeError: prop
```

I know this has to do with`__getattr__` catching the `AttributeError` but is there a nice and clean workaround for this issue? Because I can assure you, this is a debug nightmare...

Comment: Do you really mean *"how can I `raise` a better error message"*? Also, bear in mind that `a.prop` calls `a.__getattr__('prop')`, which (if it didn't raise an error) would call `a.__getattr__('some_typo')` in turn - where do you want the error to come from?

Comment: It's more about not raising a wrong error message.

Comment: Why do you think that error message is wrong? `__getattr__` is called to resolve `prop`.

Comment: Why is __getattr__ called to resolve a @property?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just raise a better exception message:

```
class A(object):
  def __getattr__(self, attr):
    if not attr.startswith("ignore_"):
      raise AttributeError("%r object has not attribute %r" % (self.__class__.__name__, attr))

  @property
  def prop(self):
    return self.some_typo

a=A()
a.ignore_this
a.prop
```

**EDIT**: calling `__getattribute__` from object base class solves the problem

```
class A(object):
  def __getattr__(self, attr):
    if not attr.startswith("ignore_"):
      return self.__getattribute__(attr)

  @property
  def prop(self):
    return self.some_typo
```

Comment: It's not about the message, it's about the typo detection. Your code raises `AttributeError: 'A' object has not attribute 'prop'`, I need it to raise `AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'some_typo'`

Comment: Great answer! I thought about overriding `__getattribute__` but I didn't like the idea of having it called each time I'm accessing something (performance issue). This is definitely the best way to do it!

Comment: The second part of the answer greatly help me in solving compatibility issues between `__getattr__()` and `@property`.
It worthwhile to note that calling `getattr(self, attr)` leads to an infinite reursion.

Comment: This fix is not correct. The way it is written, every property method will be called twice (try putting `print('calling prop')` inside of the `prop` method). A correct fix would be to **replace** `__getattr__` with `__getattribute__`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @asmeurer, the solution by @mguijarr calls `prop` twice.  When `prop` first runs, it raises an AttributeError which triggers `__getattr__`. Then `self.__getattribute__(attr)` triggers `prop` again, finally resulting in the desired exception.

**BETTER ANSWER**:

Here we are better off replacing `__getattribute__` instead of `__getattr__`. It gives us more control since `__getattribute__` is invoked on all attribute access. In contrast, `__getattr__` is only called when there has already been an `AttributeError`, and it doesn't give us access to that original error.

```py
class A(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        try:
            return super().__getattribute__(attr)
        except AttributeError as e:
            if not attr.startswith("ignore_"):
                raise e

    @property
    def prop(self):
        print("hi")
        return self.some_typo
```

To explain, since `A` subclasses `object` in this case, `super().__getattribute__(attr)` is equivalent to `object.__getattribute__(self, attr)`. That reads `a`'s underlying `object` attribute, avoiding the infinite recursion had we instead used `self.__getattribute__(attr)`.

In case of `AttributeError`, we have full control to either fail or reraise, and reraising gives a sensible error message.